# Display time correlation with Pine Script

Tags: time, correlation, pine-script

I try to find similar period in the past to the actual period for a serie. So I want to display time correlation with Pine-script by calculation for each preceeding period the correlation on 20 values between now and this preceeding periods.

Basically I display correlation like this :

```
study(title="Correlation Coeff", shorttitle="CC")
    sym = close
    seuil=0.0
    src = close [10]
    length = 20
    perf = correlation(src, sym, length)
    plot(perf, color=yellow, style=area, transp=40)
```

But it displays only correlation between the serie and the serie ten period before. How to display a correlation between the current period and each preceeding period ?

Comment: Well, `close[10]` means closing price of 10 bars ago.

Comment: Yes, it is only what I know to do with the function correlation. I don't know how to plot a correlation with each preceeding period. That means at period T, I want to plot correlation between close (now) and close(T).